# Returning const 'this' pointer

Tags: c++

if `this` is a const pointer to class's object how can you return a const pointer from non-const return type?

```
Class T
{
 public:
   T* func(){return this;}
};
```

Comment: Do you mean the pointer itself is const or the object it points to is const?

Comment: The pointer ofcourse, otherwise I would be returning a const pointer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, `this` is not a "const pointer". Where did you get that strange idea? Pointer `this` has scalar type and is not an lvalue, meaning that it can't possibly be "const" or "non-const". Pointer `this` is an rvalue and it is non-modifiable.

Secondly, the code in your question is valid regardless of whether the pointer involved is const or not. For example, the following code is valid for exactly the same reason

```
int *const p = 0; /* a const pointer */

int *foo() { 
  return p; /* OK, no error here */
}
```

What is returned in this case is a completely independent *copy* of the original pointer value. It does not matter whether `p` is const or not - making a copy of const value does not in any way violate its constness.

This is exactly what's done in your code sample - you are returning a copy of `this`'s value. Why would you even care whether `this` is const or not?

Comment: Sadly, many books claim that `this` is a constant pointer, for example *C++ Primer*.

Comment: I have asked the question after been reading from C++ Primer 4th Ed. Any good books you guys read or recommend?

Comment: @AndreyT I tried to `return this` from a const member function declared with non-const class* return type. I get an error which states cannot convert from `const T *const to T*` I think which clearly states this is being const pointer but we actually use through a 'this' keyword.

Comment: @cpx: This is a completely different story. If the member function is declared `const`, then `this` will have "pointer to const" type. (Note that in C++ "const pointer" and "pointer to const" are totally different things.) So, you indeed cannot return `this` from const member function if the return value is not a pointer to const. But what does it have to do with your original question? I don't see any references to const member functions there.

Comment: @cpx: Aklso, if your compiler claims that `this` in that case has `const T *const` type, then it must be some weird internal quirk of your compiler. `this` is a scalar rvalue and as such it can have type `T *` or `const T *`, but it cannot have `const T *const` type. Your compiler is getting it wrong.

Comment: I get this error on VS2005. I don't know if the compiler is old but I haven't read from any new books.

Comment: I'm just confused about even MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytk2ae82.aspx here states `this` as a `const pointer`. could you provide any reference?

Comment: @cpx: Some compilers might informally describe `this` as a "const pointer" (meaning that it can't be modified). However, from the formal point of view, such statements are utter nonsense. Here are my references to the language standard: 9.3.2/1 says that `this` pointer is an *rvalue* of pointer type, and 3.10/9 says that such rvalues always have *cv-unqualified* types. That's it. Again, I'm sure the VS2005 compiler implementation gets it right. It is just that the error message (and the text in MSDN) is written in an overly informal language.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the member function is const-qualified (e.g. `T* func() const` instead of just `T* func()`), `this` is of type `T*`.

`this` is not itself modifiable (so you can't assign something to `this`), but it's just a pointer to an object of type `T` like any other and can be used as such.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that being unable to edit the 'this' pointer is not an issue of typing but of the language (ie. 'this' is a keyword not an identifier)?

Comment: @Matt:  Probably.  AndeyT has provided a very good explanation of that.

Answer (score 1):

*AndreyT* provided the explanation and here is the reference.

From standard docs *9.3.2.1 The this pointer*,

> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, **the keyword this is an rvalue expression whose value is the address
>   of the object for which the function is called.** The type of this in a member function of a class X is X*. **If the member
>   function is declared const, the type of this is const X*,** if the member function is declared volatile, the type of
>   this is volatile X*, and if the member function is declared const volatile, the type of this is const volatile
>   X*.

which explains the question that you asked and the comment you made to *AndreyT*.

Hope this one also helps.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is not a object, so it does not matter if the pointer is const when it is a return value.
Consider this:

```
int x;
int f() {
    return x;
}
const int g() {
    return x;
}
```

There's actually no difference between f() and g().

But it may make difference if you replace all "int" to some other name of a class.
"const" may prevent you from some error, e.g. when you don't write a copying constructor properly.

```
class T 
{
    int *x;
public:
    T() {x = new int;}
    void set_x(int n) {*x = n;}
    int get_x() const {return *x;}
};
T a;
T f() {
    return a;
}
const T g() {
    return a;
}
int main() {
    f().set_x(123); // The value is modified
                    // even though a return value is not a l-value.
    g().set_x(123); // Compile Error
}
```

So, if you want to prevent modifying data of the object by referring to the return value, what you need is:

```
class T
{
 public:
   const T* func() const
   { return this; }
};
```